# How do I disable images in Safari 6.0?

Tags: safari

In Safari 6.0 the 'Appearance' tab from 'Preferences' was omitted.
How can I now switch “Display images when the page opens” on/off ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open Safari and go to **Preferences**, then click on the **Advanced** tab.  There's a checkbox at the bottom titled "Show Develop menu in menu bar".  Check that then close the Preferences window.

You'll notice that in your menu bar between **Bookmarks** and **Window** you have a menu called **Develop**.  Near the bottom of that menu list is **Disable Images** — click it.  Now your browsing experience is image free!

Comment: Does this **Disable Images** saves any Data usage ?

Comment: @NikhilM Yes, it does. Browser block calls to the image urls so they don't even load.