# How do I block images for one website in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, web-browsing

There is [a question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/60554/6748) on this Stack Exchange site that details how to disable images in Safari, but I only want to disable images on a website or two. How do I do this?

Comment: Seems to be an all or none proposition. I haven't run across any plugins to do what you want, either.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I've had the same experience. This is probably not currently possible.